# I can't change html text fontsize in Fl_Help_View

Tags: c++, fltk

In this example when I change textsize(30) only increased the distance of lines
but not size

```
#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/fl_ask.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Window.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Help_View.H>


int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    Fl_Window *win = new Fl_Window(640, 400, "Native File Chooser Test");
    win->size_range(win->w(), win->h(), 0, 0);
    win->begin();
    Fl_Help_View *view = new Fl_Help_View(20,20,500, 200);
    view->box(FL_FLAT_BOX);
    view->color(win->color());
#define TAB "&lt;Tab&gt;"
view->textfont(FL_HELVETICA);
Fl_Help_Font_Style(FL_HELVETICA,30,FL_RED);
```

below is html text value

```
view->value("<h2 class="city">London</h2> <p>London is the capital of England.</p>");
    view->textsize(30);


    win->end();
    win->show(argc, argv);
    return(Fl::run());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is connected with missed packages. I install libxft2 lib and now is ok.